# 404 error on a previously installed Wordpress Site in IIS 8

Tags: php, iis, windows-server, wordpress

I am hosting a Wordpress site on IIS 8 with php and fastcgi installed.

The problem is that i had to reinstall the IIS completely to install the exchange server (because it needs the Default website which was not available) including the Process Activation Service. This IIS server had the wordpress site already configured and was working fine.

The problem is when i configured the site on the same folder again. The home page is working just fine. But i am getting 404 errors on all the links as it is trying to physically locate them.

This site is owned by a client of mine and i have no idea how wordpress actually works in general. So will running the wordpress setup again will be my best bet to get it working?
Or can i get it to work in it's current state.

Comment: It sounds like IIS has not been able to support PHP. Do other PHP files work?  The fact you don't understand how Wordpress works will make it dificult to troubleshoot this problem.  Have you started your research on that subject?

Comment: Yes the php files are working fine. The problem is i don't know how wordpress handles request and/or routes, Also the resources with wordpress on IIS are pretty low. I am a .NET person so really didn't had to get into Wordpress until now.

Comment: It handles it just like any other PHP file.  Do you get a wordpress error or do you attempt to download the file or do you get some other error.  Did you configure wordpress to connect to the same database that it was previously configured to work with?

Comment: Yeah, everything was same as before. Apparently i was missing a rewrite rule in web.config. Anyways thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on the site obviously changed.
Make sure that PHP is working normally and then then check out the [Wordpress's documentation on migrations](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). If you can check off all the settings from there, it should work.

Comment: After researching for a bit. It seems to be a problem with permalinks i think. It is trying to locate permalinks as the physical paths for some reason.

Comment: Apparently i was missing a rewrite rule in the web.config so as to say the problem was with permalinks all along. Anyways thanks for the help.